# why don't we have an error, after using replaceWith() method on a constant object reference value?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, object-reference

I have trouble comprehending, why this code has no errors,
aren't we changing reference value by using the replaceWith() method?

```
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.replaceWith(btn.cloneNode(true));
```

Comment: Why would there be an error?

Comment: aren't we changing reference value with using replaceWith() method?

Comment: It's changing this DOM node with another. The method wouldn't exist if it was impossible for it to work.

Comment: but isn't btn constant a reference value to this DOM node? so when we replace the element node with another, we are refering to another element right? shouldn't we say the reference has changed?

Comment: No, the element is replaced in the DOM. The variable `btn` still links to the old node. `.replaceWith()` does not perform reassignment of a variable.

Comment: Declaring a variable `const` just prevents you reassigning it with `btn = somethingElse;`. It doesn't prevent assigning properties of the value or calling methods of the value.

Comment: Think of it this way: `const foo = { a: 'b' }`. You can still write `foo.a = 'c'`. [MDN `replaceWith` docs](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith)

Comment: we can change properties of a constant object but we can't change the reference by reassining another reference to an object to the constant, i know that, the thing i don't know is, what exactly happens to the old element node when we replace an element node with another? does our constant still have access to the old node? is it still holding the reference to the old element node? if it is, why changing the properties of this constant don"t change the old element node?

Comment: "*what exactly happens to the old element node when we replace an element node with another?*" nothing. The DOM tree and the variables are not related in any way. Calling `.replaceWith()` does not change the variable. "*is it still holding the reference to the old element node?*" yes. "*if it is, why changing the properties of this constant don"t change the old element node?*" it does? I don't really understand that question, though. Changing `btn` changes the node it points to. If it's not part of the DOM, you cannot see the changes in the: UI https://jsfiddle.net/zopetyv6/